# Generating a partially ordered random list of numbers

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, sorting

I want to generate a list of random numbers of size 500, where the list is exactly 30% sorted (I know how to generate a list of at least 30% sorted), but that's not what i want, how do i generate a file that is "exactly" 30%? I'm stuck, How can this be done?

Here is the exact wording
"For the sorts, you should construct three different files of each size: ordered, keys in reverse order, and finally one in which 30% of the keys are ordered. The latter file should not consist of files in which your sort is 30% complete, but rather in files in which 30% of the keys are correctly placed with respect to one another but are not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: What do you mean by 30% sorted, can you please give an example ?

Comment: What does "30% sorted" mean?  What if the list of random numbers came out already in sorted order?

Comment: I created a list of 500 random numbers. and i randomly take out 150 numbers into another array and sort it, after i sort it i put it back into the orginal array. But this is not Exactly 30%， it's at least 30%, what can i do so that it is exactly 30% sorted?

Comment: ok. And what property do you think that list of 500 random numbers would have?

Comment: It's a random number between 1 - 100000. Is this what you are asking for? Arunmoezhi

Comment: Suppose I gave you a list of numbers. Can you list the tests you would apply to tell whether it is a satisfactory list for your purposes?

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by '30%' sorted.  Do you care about ordering? Position?  If I have the numbers 1-10, is `1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7,8,9` 30% sorted because only three numbers are in the same location they would be if the list were fully sorted, or do you consider that 90% sorted, since only one number is out of order?

Comment: Well one test would be to sort that array using some sorting algorithm and then compare that 20% sorted to another random array that is not 20% sorted.

Comment: @HellMan The problem with that is that a random generated array can be completely sorted when created.  How do you tell a 'it started out sorted' array from a 'I had to work to get it this way' array?

Comment: AzureFrog: You just ask the biggest questiong that i did not get to, I was think about inversions. If we have a list of 500 elements, we would have n(n-1)/2 = 124750. so 124750*(3/10) = 37425 would consider 30% ordered

Comment: @azurefrog  Or would i consider this as 30%  A list of 3 2 10 7 6 4 7 1 9 5.  Since 2 and 10 , 4 and 7, 1 and 9 are sorted. Now my professor is confusing the hell out of us. azurefrog, which property do you think makes sense to you?

Comment: @user3558734 If this is an assignment, please quote or link to the exact wording.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan  the exact wording, i hope it looks clear to you.

Comment: It at least suggests a test approach - iterate over the pairs of numbers, counting how many in order and how many reversed.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan do you mean like this? A list of 3 2 10 7 6 4 7 1 9 5. Since 2 and 10 , 4 and 7, 1 and 9 are sorted.

Comment: @user3558734 I don't know. That is something to ask your professor. I see more sorted pairs than you do. For example, (2,7), (2,6), (2,7), (2,9), (2,5) all look sorted to me. I also don't know whether to count the duplicated (2,7) once or twice.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I guess i just have to go back to my professors then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main ideas I can see for percentage sorted:

- Simply the number of elements out of place.

  Once should be able to get an estimated % sorted by sorting it, then iterating through it, and, keeping each element the same with the desired percentage as probability, otherwise swapping it with a random remaining element (so, if we want 30% sorted, we'll keep an element the same with 30% probability, and swap it with 70%).

  If an exact number is needed, one could use the above result and (intelligently) swap random elements until the desired percentage is obtained.
- The number of [inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29).

  > An inversion is a pair of places of a sequence where the elements on these places are out of their natural order.

  One idea is to first sort it, then to swap random elements that get us closer to the desired percentage sorted, until we get there.

  Only swapping elements that get us closer to the desired result is difficult (at least doing so efficiently).

  - A very brute force approach would be to count the change in the number of inversions that each pair of swaps would cause, and then pick a random one that gets us closer to our target.
  - Another idea is to just generate random pairs and count the number of inversions until we find one that gets us closer.
  - A third option is to pick a random element. If it's larger than half the elements, try to move it left (ideally increasing the number of inversions). If it's smaller, try to move it right. In trying to move it left/right, we can look for a smaller / larger element (respectively) to swap it with and count the change in inversions (we only need to consider the elements between the swapped elements when counting the change in inversions).

  At first we could probably just randomly swap elements as we're likely to tend to more inversions.

  If the percentage is above 50%, we could also start with a reversed array, i.e. 100% unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a one-to-one correspondence that maps permutations to {0} x {0, 1} x {0, 1, 2} x ... x {0, 1, ... n - 1}, where the jth element of the tuple in the codomain is the number of inversions involving elements at positions j and i < j. In this light, the problem is sampling a random element of the codomain that sums to the desired number of inversions.

Here's an instance of [Gibbs sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) for this problem. Initialize a tuple summing to the desired number of permutations. Repeatedly select two distinct indices and randomize uniformly among all possibilities with the same sum. Stop when you're tired of waiting (the distribution converges on uniform but never gets there; maybe tomorrow I will figure out a Propp--Wilson style technique for exact samples).

In Python (untested):

```
import random

def gibbs(n, target):
    perm = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        perm[i] = min(target, i)
        target -= i
    assert target == 0
    while ???:
        i = random.randrange(n)
        j = random.randrange(n)
        if i == j: continue
        total = perm[i] + perm[j]
        perm[i] = random.randrange(max(total - j, 0), i + 1)
        perm[j] = total - perm[i]
    for j in range(n):
        perm[j] = j - perm[j]
        for i in range(j):
            if perm[i] >= perm[j]: perm[i] += 1
    return perm
```

One could also get exact samples by dynamic programming and conditional probability, but the running time for 500 looks slightly prohibitive from here.